# How to deploy sql server database at client side?

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Hi i am new here in developing Window Based Application using .NET.
how we can deploy the database at client side i am using SQL Server 2008.
Is it required this or we need to install that software at client side ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install SQL Server on your client pc ([Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx) could be good if you're familiar with its limits).
Then your app can use database file as in your development pc.

Comment: is it necessary to create database table after installing the setups ?

Comment: @VikrantMore: I'm quite sure you can simply distribute your MDF file

Answer (score 1):

If by deploying a database clientside, you mean use a database on the local machine, you probably want to locally pipe mySQL, or use SQLLite. If your asking if a someone who download your software will also need an SQL databse on their side when using your software the answer is still yes.

Comment: is it possible to do a pipeline for SQLSERVER database ?